# Adding current time to INTO OUTFILE 'C:/Output/data_.csv'

Tags: mysql, windows, timestamp

I am looking for a way to add the current time to my filename after every new export.

Current code:

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'C:/Output/data_.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' FROM eloge_collector;
```

What i want to achieve:

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'C:/Output/data_2018-05-10-15-14.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' FROM collector;
```

or something like this.

Comment: What code do you use to execute the statement? If you are using PHP for example, you could create the filename in the PHP code before you execute the statement.

Comment: Another option is to use [13.5 Prepared SQL Statement Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

Comment: i am running it with command line and would like to schedule later to make it automatic,  it is working fine, but i have to rename every file to make it really auto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use prepared statements to create your query string then executing it
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

this is my solution

first create create variable to hold the query string.

use concat function to inject current date time to the query string.

use DATE_FORMAT and now functions to get current date time

```
set @sql = concat("SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'C:/filePrefix_",DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m%d%H%i%s'),".fileExtension' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' FROM `table`");
prepare s1 from @sql; --create statment from variable 
execute s1; -- execute prepared statements
```

Comment: i'll look into it and get back to you if its working or not, thanks